# Error when using Moq.Times with ?: operator

Tags: c#, mocking, operators

I try to test my code using Moq framework, and I would like to verify if my methods are called or not in some special cases. For this I have to use Mock.Times. If I use Times likes this it works properly.

```
MockObject.Verify(x => x.SomeMethod(), Times.Once)
```

But because I have many methods to check I want to use it this way:

```
System.Func<Times> times = isItCalled ? Times.Once : Times.Never;
MockObject.Verify(x => x.SomeMethod(), times)
```

And for this I get the following error message:
**Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'method group' and 'method group'.**

That is really weird for me, because I thought this operator is same as the following (which also work properly):

```
 System.Func<Times> times;
 if (isItCalled)
 {
    times = Times.Once;
 }
 else
 {
    times = Times.Never;
 }
 MockObject.Verify(x => x.SomeMethod(), times)
```

Comment: Could you try this: `System.Func<Times> times = isItCalled ? ((System.Func<Times>)Times.Once) : Times.Never;`

Comment: Thank you very much!! It works! But could you please explain me why is this explicit casting necessary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known issue with the ternary operator.

A possible solution:

```
Func<Times> times = isItCalled ? (Func<Times>)Times.Once : Times.Never;
MockObject.Verify(x => x.SomeMethod(), times);
```

Or:

```
// note the parentheses so you pass a Time instance instead of a delegate:
MockObject.Verify(x => x.SomeMethod(), isItCalled ? Times.Once() : Times.Never());
```